# How can I get an OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect token from Firebase on Android?

Tags: android, oauth, firebase, openid, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get an OAuth 2.0 token from FirebaseUser when it's integrated with Google Sign-in? The constructor I am using (`CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider`) needs either an OpenID Connect token or an OAuth 2.0 token.

Currently, I use `GoogleSignInAccount.getIdToken` to retrieve a JWS Web token, which Firebase takes to authenticate the user with its backend. However, the only method Firebase provides to retrieve another token after that is

```
public Task<GetTokenResult> getToken (boolean forceRefresh)
```

which simply returns a "`Firebase Auth ID Token`" (from the docs).

Is this similar to what I am looking for? Or is there a way to convert it perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: What are you looking for exactly, Yes from the docs 
Firebase ID tokens conform to the the OpenID Connect spec and contain data to identify a user, as well as some other profile and authentication related information